# How to deploy a static website on AWS?

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, httpd.conf

I bought a domain name, e.g. www.mydomain.com. Also I have the Amazon EC2 instance. I uploaded the folder with website files to `/var/www/html/mywebsite`.

What I want to do is to link a public DNS of the EC2 instance to `www.mydomain.com`. When a user opens `www.mydomain.com`, he/she should see what I have in `/var/www/html/mywebsite` of the EC2 instance.

To reach this goal, I changed the configuration of the server in EC2 instance (`httpd.conf`):

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mywebsite
ServerName www.mydomain.com:80
```

And restarted the server `sudo service httpd restart`.

When I go to `www.mydomain.com`, I do not see the content of `/var/www/html/mywebsite`. Which steps have I missed?

P.S. I found many articles explaining how to deploy static websites on Amazon S3. However, I don't want to use S3.

Comment: dns propagation can take upto 24 hours

Comment: @YashKumarVerma: The steps that I made are enough or did I miss something?

Comment: @YashKumarVerma Why my question was down voted by you? Please explain if you decided to downvote.

Comment: https://ibb.co/gpwqBc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you setup DNS so that your domains/subdomains point/connect to your AWS EC2 instance?

Comment: No, I haven't done it. When I open a dashboard of the website where I bought a domain, I see two DNS servers. I can create personalised servers (I assume that this is what you mean), but I asked to provide at least two DNS servers. I have 1 public DNS in Amazon EC2. How should I put 2?

Comment: I can of course simply redirect from `www.mydomain.org` to Amazon EC2 instance (its public IP address), but this is not what I want.

Comment: Normally when I purchase a domain - I get DNS service include and just create "A" records for www.mydomain.com and point to IP address.  and "A" record for mydomain.com and point to IP address.  If you see two DNS server - that for DNS Nameservers.  (servers that provide DNS lookup for your records).  - you could do Amazon Route53 - create DNS records and get Amazon DNS nameserver and use those